# I rooted my phone, uninstalled google play store but now I need it. What can I do?

Tags: google-play-store, rooting

My phone is "Smile N2". I rooted it an it turned from kitkat to lollipop. I also uninstalled the google play store. I used kingroot to do this. But now I badly need the google play store.

I took it from my friend using shareit. I installed it. But then it crushed. I tried to add a google account on my phone. But It says it can't reach to the google sarver. I uninstalled Kingroot somehow.

But this didn't unroot my phone. Now please tell me what can I do?

Comment: Flash the stock ROM on your device

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: Search in XDA or your device forums

Comment: can I do this without pc?

Comment: If you just want to access the Playstore, use the [Yalp Store](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.github.yeriomin.yalpstore/) app. However, if you need to buy an app, or use one that needs to check its license with Google, that won't help.

Comment: You need a computer in order to flash your device. It is probably a mediatek Powered phone.

Comment: You can try mounting /system and copy Play Store apk to /system/apk the restart device.